# How to adapt a GUI developed with PyQt5 based on screen resolution?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am developing a tool which will be subject to be used on different computers and by consequence on different screen resolution. I tried the followings codes to adapt my GUI to different resolutions but nothing changes when I try different resolutions such as 2736 x 1824 or 800 x 600:

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from frontend_test import Ui_MainWindow

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1

class Test(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Test()
    prog.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With a resolution of 2736 x 1824, I get the following visualization (what I want):
[image]

And with a resolution of 800 x 600, I get the following visualisation:
[image]